# Firebase cloud functions code ELIFECYCLE error

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to deploy the initial code provided by `firebase init` for cloud functions by calling `firebase deploy` the following error occurs. The source code inside `index.ts` has not been modified as it is the case with the rest of the project.

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/eliasdolinsek/development/firebase-development/functions
> tsc

../../../node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:195:87 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'Dir'.

195 export function opendir(path: string, cb: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, dir: fs.Dir) => void): void;
                                                                                          ~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:198:17 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'OpenDirOptions'.

198     options: fs.OpenDirOptions,
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:199:53 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'Dir'.

199     cb: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, dir: fs.Dir) => void,
                                                        ~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:201:52 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'OpenDirOptions'.

201 export function opendir(path: string, options?: fs.OpenDirOptions): Promise<fs.Dir>;
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:201:80 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'Dir'.

201 export function opendir(path: string, options?: fs.OpenDirOptions): Promise<fs.Dir>;
                                                                                   ~~~


Found 5 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/eliasdolinsek/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T13_18_50_649Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

Comment: You mind including what is in the `$RESOURE_DIR` environment variable?

Comment: @shn when entering it in the terminal nothing is being displayed

Comment: which is your `typescript` version and which platform `OS` you work on ?

Comment: @Hitheshk Version 4.1.3 with macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `typeRoots` to the `tsconfig.json` within the functions folder

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./functions/node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
}
```

[check out this Github issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/749#issuecomment-513518950)